# git push hangs weird

Tags: linux, git

When I want to push new contents to my Github, I used

```
git push
or
git pull
```

It's not working, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUUJg.png) but I used it successfully one hour before.
So I tried

```
git push origin master
```

Now it's success, magic.
But I don't know why about it, and how I need to do to go back that just needs input 2 words.

I tried

```
git config --global sendpack.sidehand false
```

Thanks in advance.

Add:

```
git push -u origin master
```

told me "Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin"
I know that's right, but git push still can't work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration you mentioned is unrelated to your problem (you should probably undo that). If you want to set up the `master` branch on the `origin` remote repository as the default branch to push to from your current branch, run once

```
git push -u origin master
# or
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

and then use just `git push` afterwards.

Comment: thank you, but It's still doesn't work. And when I input "git pull", the same as push's problem arisen. No any error message, but I must use Ctrl+C to stop it.